# VBA: save a Word doc to two places

Tags: vba, ms-word

What I would like to achieve is to save a Word document in two places using the `Save` function. It has two shortcomings, though. First, Word blinks when I save a file (because it closes saves a copy, and it becomes active document, which is closed, and then Word return to the original document). Second, macro add my backup to recent files, despite `AddToRecentFiles:=False` How to avoid two faults?

```
Sub FileSave()
Dim currFile As String
Dim backup As String
backup = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Documents\WordBackups\"
With ActiveDocument
If .Saved Or .Path = "" Then Exit Sub
If Dir(backup, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir backup
    MsgBox "Backup folder has been created.", vbInformation
End If

    .Bookmarks.Add Name:="LastPosition"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    .Save
    currFile = .FullName
    .SaveAs2 FileName:=backup & .Name, AddToRecentFiles:=False

End With

    ActiveDocument.Close
    Documents.Open FileName:=currFile
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="LastPosition"
```

End Sub

Comment: Reading and understanding the code would be a good start, maybe? Seriously, you copy code off the Internet and run it (!) without having the slightest clue how it does what it does? This is extremely... unwise.

Comment: First of all, you should remove the line On Error Result Next as that will hide any errors - and it could be important to know what errors are generated!

Comment: @Cindy Those are 18 lines of perfectly obvious code, at least to anyone putting in a few minutes of their time to attempt to understand them. The OP apparently did not make such an attempt. Explaining what this code is doing is an exercise in futility.

Comment: Yes, that thought did cross my mind. OTOH this is supposed to be Q&A, meaning the explanation could help others, coming later. So I compromised and provided "homework" rather than giving the corrected code in my answer... :-)

Comment: @Tomalak Reading carefully is always a good start if one wants to comment on somebody's post. If you had done it, you would have known that I wrote "macro saves a current document when Word closes" (!). I have no idea how you could arrive at conclusion that I did read nor tried to understand the code.

Comment: You wrote: "Seriously, you copy code off the Internet and run it (!) without having the slightest clue how it does what it does? This is extremely... unwise".  How did you know that I had no "the slightest clue how it does what it does"? Can you read in my mind? Or were you behind my back to see what I was doing? Seriosly, I could not tell if I had understood the code. You could *guess*. I explicitly wrote that the code *saves* and not I *think* the code saves. If you still think that you know better what I did or did not, or I thought, please do not continue this issue any longer.

Answer (score 1):

This code checks whether the document has changes that need saving. If there are none, the back-up is made. Otherwise, if the document has a file path (has been saved before) the document is saved and the code restarts, then the back-up will be made. Otherwise, the Save As dialog box is shown so that the document can be saved to a path, then the back-up is made.

The tricky part is how the macro should differentiate between "I've only opened and looked at it" vs. "the document has been saved, now make a back-up".

One possibility would be to check for the presence of a document Variable or document Property, set by the Save action and removed by SaveAs. Try this:

1. File/Info; from the "Properties" dropdown choose "Advanced Properties".
2. Create a Custom property named MakeBackup as a "Yes/No" type and set it to No.
3. After the line .Save: `ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("MakeBackup").Value = True`
4. Add a check to the If for the backup to check whether this is true: `If .Saved And ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("MakeBackup").Value = True Then`
5. And after the SaveAs2 line change it back to false: `ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("MakeBackup").Value = False`

Comment: Not creating a copy/paste snippet was a smart move. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and sorry for my late reply. I was sick and not able to work at my computer. I have updated the code in my first post and I did the 1st point you suggested. Now when I close Word, it wants my to save the copy of my document. Quite strange because .SaveAs2 should do this automatically. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please be more explicit about "...it wants to save a copy of my document." What is happening, exactly, that you don't expect/want? Is this a new document or an existing one that already has a file path? And does the file path contain a forward slash (/), as speicifed in ElseIf? You might also try setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code to see under what circumstances which logic it follows.

Comment: @CindyMeister Please give me one day or two to rewrite this code. I now think that it would be better to make a backup whenever a document is saved. To my knowledge, it would be better to avoid the first point of your suggestion. I could be wrong, but this way the macro would work regardless of a document contains a property named MakeBackup or is based on a template (e.g. normal.dot) that contains this property.

Comment: Yes, if you alter the approach so that a backup is made whenever there's a save you don't need "to jump through hoops".

Comment: @CindyMeister I have rewritten the code and it works, however there are two imperfections I would like to fix. Could you have a look at my first post, please?

Comment: It's not a good idea to make a major change to your original question which then invalidates all the discussion associated with it. That makes things very confusing. Better is to leave the original, use EDIT and add  new information below it with follow-up explanation. Please do this.